# No center strut in door for opener

Tags: garage-door-opener

Installed Genie Garage door (8' X 12') motor and chain rail with extension added. I am ready to attach it to the door but there is no center rail built into the door.  Are there parts for this or do I begin fabrication?

Comment: How about a picture of the door, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

My door has flat sections with no panel design . I wanted something stronger than thin aluminum to attach the opener to , so I added a piece of 1/2 plywood about 48" X 16" to the aluminum using 21 screws ( I just went out and counted them ).  Then attached the door pull to the plywood . Possibly overkill but after white paint no one knows it is there.

Answer (score 1):

Most segmented doors have sections with no vertices, the company I use (overhead door company) connects the opener to the top horizontal zonal section. On larger doors they sometimes add a strap to the bottom of the first section. The door is balanced by the torsion springs so the opener is really pulling or pushing that hard. 
I would follow the mfg instructions, a cross brace from the top rail to the bottom rail of the first section sounds like a good idea and I have repaired doors that had ripped out the top rail by adding a vertical strap after the spring was replaced but many times only connection to the top rail is all that is needed.